# Combine multiple triggers with multiple branches

Tags: github, continuous-integration, workflow, github-actions

How can we run github workflows on multiple branches for multiple triggers? Example - How can I run a workflow on `pull_request` & `push` on say `prod` & `dev`? Refer the code snippet below

```yaml
on: [push, pull_request]
  branches:    
    - 'dev'
    - 'prod'
```

The above isn't allowed. I get the following error -

```
Property branches is not allowed.yaml-schema: GitHub Workflow
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have [multiple events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-multiple-events) triggering your workflow with subtypes.

Therefore, to achieve what you want (*run a workflow on pull_request & push on prod & dev*), you would need this implementation:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:    
      - 'dev'
      - 'prod'

  pull_request:
    branches:    
      - 'dev'
      - 'prod'
```

The problem in your implementation was that the `branches` isn't a `on` subtype in github actions, it's only a `pull_request` or `push` subtype.

Comment: Thanks, very much! Accepted & Upvoted :)